# for loop is using only the first query value again and again

Tags: python

I have a query output which will bring 4 millions records in realtime . What i am trying to do is i will run a query which will bring some records and i am trying to pass the records one by one inside a for loop and perform a particular action .

But what happening is only the first record from the query goes again and again inside the for loop

```
 query = "select  id from owner limit 10"
print (query)
cursor.execute(query)
contact = cursor.fetchall()
print(contact)
for info in contact:
    id = contact[0][0]
    print(id)
for row in info:
    print (id)
    ivurl = f'{api}/company/{row}/contacts?'
    payload: Dict[str, Union[bool, int]] = {'owner': True}
    response = get_iv_response(url=ivurl, payload=payload)
    email_contact_totalresult: int = response.get('totalResults')
    email = int(email_contact_totalresult)
    if email > 0:
        print("this contact has email")
```

this is the output

```
this is the result from the query
[(167806,), (167806,), (50791734,), (7615365,), (641219,), (6990522,),(4943654,), (4943654,)]
```

this is the result from the for loop
167806
167806
167806
167806
167806
167806
167806
167806
167806
167806
167806
this contact has email

Comment: Don't really understand your code. But for your second for loop, shouldn't it be inside the first for loop. Now "info" variable only holds one value.

Comment: so how to pass query values one by one inside the for loop sir!

Comment: do you know what is nested for loop?

Comment: is the line  'id = contact[0][0]' really needed?
What you are doing there is assign the first value of contact '(167806,)' to id.
In case you remove it it should work

Comment: i think i can not use nested for loop since it is a query output , pls correct me if i am mistaken

Comment: @andi the return valued from query have some special char to remove it i am using it , i too think the problem is there , since i am a beginner , guide me to remove the special char when i am passing the values inside the for loop

Comment: @dr.engg i see no special character there tho, can you give me an example for it?

Comment: the output from the query should be int , so that i can pass it to another api , but the query return [(167806,), instead of 167806 and thats y i am using [0][0] in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to do something like:

```
contact = [(167806,), (167806,), (50791734,), (7615365,), (641219,), (6990522,),(4943654,), (4943654,)]
print(contact)
for id in contact:
    print(id[0])
    ivurl = f'{api}/company/{id[0]}/contacts?'
    payload: Dict[str, Union[bool, int]] = {'owner': True}
    response = get_iv_response(url=ivurl, payload=payload)
    email_contact_totalresult: int = response.get('totalResults')
    email = int(email_contact_totalresult)
    if email > 0:
        print("this contact has email")
```

I believe the line which was at fault was `id = contact[0][0]`
As you were assigning the first value of contact to id.
But if you would like to take the first value of id, which in this case is a tuple, you could do something like `id[0]`

Comment: exactly but except the first value alone keeps on repeating inside the for loop

Comment: @dr.engg can you please try again with the new code? As in my tests it does not repeat

Comment: when i give the values as constant in the code it works perfectly fine , but when using the query it still cause the same issue

Comment: oh i see, can you modify the line `cursor.fetchall()` to `list(cursor.fetchall())` and either try the code again or comment the output? Also modify the `'ivurl = f'{api}/company/{id[0]}/contacts?'` to `ivurl = f'{api}/company/{id}/contacts?'`

Comment: thanks mate it worked , there was a indentation issue which made this issue

Comment: Glad to hear that, please do not forget to mark the answer as helpful in case it was  so other people will know too :)